# How to use image with two push buttons in matlab guide?

Tags: database, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, data-import

everyone have problem programing in guide, so in guide i opened image with file selector in this i use pushbutton1, so now i want so save this image into database using pushbutton2, always got error on : Undefined function or variable 'image_str'.

Error in pildymas>pushbutton2_Callback (line 291) nuotrauka = {[1],'.jpg',image_str,[42],[42]};

add code below:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg','*.bmp'},'File Selector');
image1 = imread(strcat(pathname, filename));
axes(handles.axes1);
I = imshow(image1);
I = I(:)'; % transpose it
I = im2uint8(I); % convert it to uint8
s = dec2hex(I, 2)'; % convert it to hexcode
image_str = s(:)'; 
handles.image_str=0;
guidata(hObject,handles)
clear I s
 % save the updated handles object
 guidata(hObject,handles);
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%Use handles structure to recall the selected file
conn = database('baze', 'root', 'root', 'Vendor', 'MYSQL', 'Server', 'localhost', 'PortNumber', 3306);
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');
vardas = get(handles.edit1, 'string');
pavarde = get(handles.edit2, 'string');
laipsnis = get(handles.edit3, 'string');
pareigos = get(handles.edit4, 'string');
telefonas = get(handles.edit5, 'string');
marke = get(handles.edit6, 'string');
numeris = get(handles.edit7, 'string');
tarnyba = get(handles.edit8, 'string');
handles.image_str=0;
nuotrauka = {[1],'.jpg',image_str,[42],[42]}; 
guidata(hObject, handles);
exdata = {vardas,pavarde,laipsnis,pareigos,telefonas,marke,numeris,tarnyba,nuotrauka};
fastinsert(conn, 'info', {'vardas','pavarde','laipsnis','pareigos','telefonas','marke','numeris','tarnyba','nuotrauka'},exdata)
close(conn);
```

thanks in advise.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully first add `handles.image_str=0` to `OpeningFcn` but you add this to `pushbutton11_callback` function -and next step `handles.img_str=s(:)'` and next `nuotrauka = {[1],'.jpg',handles.image_str,[42],[42]};`

Comment: i do this opening function

Comment: now i little change code look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215492/how-to-save-image-in-database-matlab

Comment: your previous error is solved? are you get concept? if your problem is solved,then apply answer

Answer (score 0):

Variables in each function is local, this means that `image_str` only define in `pushbutton1_callback` function and not define in `pushbutton2_callback` so you must define this variable in `handles` structure

check [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922215/how-to-display-desired-image-in-matlab-gui/43924530#43924530) for much information

for gentle answer you can try following steps:

1. **define variable that shared in whole functions**

define a variable in `OpeningFcn` like below code

```
handles.image_str=0;
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

2. **save image in `pushbutton1_callback` function**

save image in `handles.img_str` like below

```
handles.image_str=0;
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

3. **Use handles.image_str**

now you can use `handles.image_str` every where you like

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'image_str'.

Error in pildymas>pushbutton2_Callback (line 291) nuotrauka = {[1],'.jpg',image_str,[42],[42]};